How to configure custom preloaded js files in vite
After Vite is packaged, a piece of code like this will be added to the HTML
<link rel="modulepreload" crossorigin href="./static/js/vue-6yrc7NEg.js">

How can I customize the addition, for example, to continue adding the following code based on the original
 <link rel="modulepreload" crossorigin href="./static/js/axios-13YDFsaxG.js">
The static directory is generated after subpackaging
I tried to write a plug-in to get it, but it couldn't get the HTML file, but it could get other files except HTML after packaging.
